# How to get the following query?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Hello I have two columns appt_number and status I am interested in the rows with duplicated appt_number such as:

```
            appt_number     status
191624     100001718895   complete
41105      100001718895    notdone
```

I would like just to get all the values with notdone at first and then something else like the example of the above,
for instance this case is not important for me:

```
81735      100002203648  cancelled
81738      100002203648  suspended
```

since it does not start with notdone

I tried:

```
print(df[['appt_number','status']]).sort(['appt_number'],ascending=True)
```

however I got, so I need to clean this result in order to get the desired cases:

```
            appt_number     status
140935     100000444380   complete
77626        1000011340   complete
222687     100001204805   complete
191624     100001718895   complete
41105      100001718895    notdone
293961     100002049980   complete
81735      100002203648  cancelled
81738      100002203648  suspended
76059      100003318442   complete
287598     100003867456   complete
7733       100004968279   complete
276560     100006105890   complete
166713      10000685700   complete
```

So I would really appreciate the support to overcome this difficult task, 
After a useful feedback I tried:

```
df['counter'] = df.groupby('appt_number').status.transform('size')
df = df[df.counter >=2]
df = df[df['status'].isin(['cancelled','complete','notdone','pending','suspended'])]
#df = df[df.status == 'notdone']
print(df[['appt_number', 'status']].sort(['appt_number'],ascending=True))
```

however I got:

```
            appt_number     status
41105      100001718895    notdone
191624     100001718895   complete
81738      100002203648  suspended
81735      100002203648  cancelled
227320     100011167163    pending
274408     100011167163  suspended
241047     100011167163  suspended
274414     100011167163   complete
274409     100011167163  suspended
137816     100012143654   complete
```

but I am just interested in the things that at first were notdone and then changed like this:

```
            appt_number     status
41105      100001718895    notdone
191624     100001718895   complete
```

So I really would appreciate the support to get just these cases.

Comment: can you post df.head(15)? It gets easier to work with the real data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the trick:

In:

```
df = df[['appt_number','status']].sort_values(by='appt_number', ascending=True)
df2 = df.loc[df.status == 'notdone']
df3 = pd.merge(df, df2, on='appt_number')
df3
```

Out:

```
    appt_number     status_x    status_y
0   101420561364    notdone     notdone
1   139015260682    notdone     notdone
...
n   139144839318    notdone     notdone
```

Answer (score 0):

try this little fella

```
df['counter'] = df.groupby('appt_number').status.transform('size')
df = df[df.counter >=2]
df = df[df.status == 'notdone']
```

Comment: thanks but there is still a part to have the complete solution, however I really appreciate the support.